# Error running Java Unit Test. Don't manage to import packages related to annotation "@Test" and method "equalTo()"

Tags: java, unit-testing

***Please help me. I am trying to run a unit test in a Java code (simple code I am running as part of Java trainning), but I don't manage to import the packages related to the annotation "@Test" and method "equalTo()" in AccountTest class (see the code below).***

Here is the setup information:

- I have tried to run this code using IDE's "Eclipse Java Oxygen" and "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2020-03";
- I have updated the JDK to version 13 (I have updated PATH system variable adding the file directory "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin");
- I am using JRE 1.8.0_241;
- OS: Windows 7 Professional;

Code of Unit Test (here is the problem), AccountTest class:

```
public class AccountTest {

    @Test // Eclipse error reported: "Test cannot be resolved to a type". It does not offer to import the package related to the annotation "@Test"
    public void onWithdrawalBalanceShouldBeReduced() {
        Account account = new Account(200d);
        account.withdraw(50d);

        assertThat(account.getBalance(), is(equalTo(150d))); // Eclipse error reported: "The method equalTo(Double) is undefined for the type AccountTest". It does not offer to import the package related to method "equalTo()"
    }
}
```

Code for Account Class:

```
public class Account {

    private double balance;

    public Account(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public void withdraw(double value) {
        this.balance = this.balance + value;
    }

    public void deposit(double valor) {
        this.balance = this.balance + valor;
    }

    public void setBalance(double saldo) {
        this.balance = saldo;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Code for Bank Class:

```
public class Bank {

    public void deposit(Account account, double value) {
        account.deposit(value);
    }

    public void doTranference(Account account1, double value, Account account2) {
        account1.withdraw(value);
        account2.deposit(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You must have JUnit on the classpath in order to build and run your tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the JUnit library is on your build path.
Your Eclipse version has built-in JUnit3, JUnit4, and JUnit5 libraries.

You should try to create a new JUnit test case using menu command:
`File/New/JUnit Test Case` and select one of the following options:
[image: New JUnit Test Case Dialog]

- New Junit3 Test
- New Junit4 Test
- New Junit Jupiter Test

Type in the class name of your test (and package if needed), press `Finish` button and you'll get to the dialog to add appropriate JUnit library to your build path.
[image: Add Junit4 library to the build path]

Press `OK` button and then you can add/edit your test class.

```java
package my.task;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

class AccountTest {

    @Test
    public void onWithdrawalBalanceShouldBeReduced() {
        Account account = new Account(200d);
        account.withdraw(50d);

        assertEquals("Account balance should be reduced to 150", 150d, account.getBalance(), 0.001);
    }
}
```

Please also note the following points:

- method `withdraw` in `Account` does not actually subtract the withdrawal amount and the test will fail:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Account balance should be reduced to 150 expected:<150.0> but was:<250.0>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)
    at my.task.AccountTest.onWithdrawalBalanceShouldBeReduced(AccountTest.java:14)
    ...
```

- generally it is not recommended to use floating point type for balance because it may lead to unwanted rounding errors :)
- if you really need to use `assertThat`, and hamcrest matchers `is()` and `equalTo`, you'll need to fix the imports:

```java
package my.task;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat; 
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class AccountTest {

    @Test
    public void onWithdrawalBalanceShouldBeReduced() {
        Account account = new Account(200d);
        account.withdraw(50d);

        assertThat(account.getBalance(), is(equalTo(150d)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Alex. You solved my problem! Thank you very much! I intentionally made a mistake on withdraw method to get the error during the test. Have a great weekend. :)

Comment: Alex, what is the 0.001 parameter used for in "assertEquals("Account balance should be reduced to 150", 150d, account.getBalance(), 0.001);"? I tried to open the assertEquals() method to check the documentation, but I did not manage.

Comment: Should I report your answer as the solution to the problem? If yes, I am not managing to find the option to do that. How do I do that. This is the first question I do in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi Dênis!  You're welcome! :)

0.001 is a delta parameter used to compare `double` values in JUnit.  Method `assertEquals(double, double)` is deprecated.

Comment: To accept an answer, you should click on the check mark beside an answer to toggle it to green: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers